# Bug to add custom formulas when I update pivot table

Tags: google-apps-script, pivot-table

I am developing a tool that allows me to follow different field trips for my company. Every day, a new tour is made and is archived in the "Archiving" tab. Via a function, I also add the month in which the tour was made to the archive.

Then I have a pivotTable which displays some of the data of the different tours (month, week, date and other more specific data). I want to display only the tours of the current month.

So I created a script to update this pivotTable. It recreates the entire pivotTable and replaces the month if it is not the same as last time. Everything works perfectly except for two custom formulas that allow me to display a result depending on the data (conforming or not).
Here is the formula for a compliant response → =NB.SI(COMPLIANCE_RESPONSE; TRUE)
And here is the formula for a non-compliant response → =NB.SI(COMPLIANCE_RESPONSE;FALSE)

It tells me "Formula parsing error" with #ERROR! in every cell in these two columns.

[image]

However when I select the formula in the pivotTable and press enter, the data is displayed again and I don't understand why.

Here is the function I use to update my pivotTable.

```
function triTCDSuiviUVC(){
   // Déclaration des constantes et des variables
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuilleSuiviUVC = classeur.getSheetByName("Suivi UVC");
   const feuilleArchives = classeur.getSheetByName("Archivage");

   // Récupération du nombre de lignes
   var nbArchivage = feuilleArchives.getRange("A1:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
   // Récupération de la valeur de ce mois
   var lastRowArchivage = feuilleArchives.getLastRow();
   var libMoisActuel = feuilleArchives.getRange(lastRowArchivage,2).getValue();
   // Modification du TCD
   feuilleSuiviUVC.getRange('A7').activate();
   var sourceData = feuilleSuiviUVC.getRange('Archivage!A1:Z'+nbArchivage);
   var pivotTable = feuilleSuiviUVC.getRange('A6').createPivotTable(sourceData);
   var pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(14, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.SUM);
   pivotValue.setDisplayName('Actions libres');
   pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(25, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);
   pivotValue.setDisplayName('Commentaire');
   pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(15, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.SUM);
   pivotValue.setDisplayName('Actions anomalies');
   pivotValue = pivotTable.addCalculatedPivotValue('CONFORME', '=NB.SI(CONFORMITE_REPONSE; VRAI)');
   pivotValue.summarizeBy(SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.CUSTOM);
   pivotValue = pivotTable.addCalculatedPivotValue('NON CONFORME', '=NB.SI(CONFORMITE_REPONSE;FAUX)');
   pivotValue.summarizeBy(SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.CUSTOM);
   var pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(2);
   pivotGroup.setDisplayName('Mois');
   pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(3);
   pivotGroup.showTotals(false)
   .sortDescending()
   .setDisplayName('Semaines');
   pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(6);
   pivotGroup.setDisplayName('Date des tournées');
   pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(11);
   pivotGroup.showTotals(false)
   .setDisplayName('Rituels');
   var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
   .setVisibleValues(['Rituel réalisé'])
   .build();
   pivotTable.addFilter(18, criteria);
   criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
   .setVisibleValues(['UVC'])
   .build();
   pivotTable.addFilter(13, criteria);
   criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
   .setVisibleValues([libMoisActuel])
   .build();
   pivotTable.addFilter(2, criteria);
 }
```

And [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jzWYBknNxJEvaZS74unDuP0kd1DtKlmmUSzHypor1B8/edit?usp=sharing) is the link to access the file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Do not hesitate to contact me if you need more information.

Comment: How did you create a function named NB.SI?  I get an error in script editor.

Comment: I have a mistake too. However, when I open my pivotTable in Sheets, go to the calculated field and press enter, the formula refreshes and the data appears again.

Comment: most of the code is from a macro I recorded to see how it works. And, except for the columns with the calculated fields, the rest works. So, I don't know if the error comes from the code (quotation marks problem?) or from the fact that it's not possible to add calculated fields via the appscript

Comment: I don't think NB.SI is a valid function or formula name.  You didn't answer my question, how did you create a function named NB.SI?

Comment: NB.SI is the equivalent of COUNTIF in french language ( https://www.sheets-pratique.com/fr/fonctions/nb-si). I didn't create it, it's a predefined function. I tried with COUNTIF and i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I notice that at the beginning of the month there were a lot of reports of loading issues with custom functions on Google Sheets.

If you think this is a new bug all together you can go ahead and report directly to Google by following the steps from here:

https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker

Just for reference you can also review the other [issue trackers](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222342097) that I mentioned with loading and errors, there was a new comment from today, that it might be having issues once again.